# Getting a record from SQLite?

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

How can I get a specified record from a table and row?
Example:

Here is a pseudo structure of the datebase (sqlite):

```
Row1 Row2 Row3
Line1 Line1 Line1
Line2 Line2 Line2
... ... ...
```

I want to use get a line record from the datebase via Qt.
For example how can I get Row2->**Line2** string?

I tried this:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE"); 
db.setDatabaseName("db.db"); //Yes the name of datebase is db.db
   if (db.open())
{
    QSqlQuery soruAl("SELECT question FROM questions",db);
    soruAl.exec();soruAl.first(); //These line does not affect result "QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record". 
    qDebug() << soruAl.value(5).toString(); // Here I want to get the 5. line of the question row which is in questions table.
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "Error";
}
```

But only response I get from debugger is "QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record"

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000123/qsqlquery-not-positioned-on-a-valid-record

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong. Here's [the example of doing it right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561175/cant-execute-mysql-querys-with-qt/15569023#15569023)

Also I recommend you to read [QtSqlQuery help](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html) carefully - it all described there. Great help is one of the strongest advantages of using Qt.